# FDR and Bonferroni corrections and Logistic Regression / Classification in High Dimensional Space

Tags: logistic, classification, bonferroni, high-dimensional, false-discovery-rate

My work involves Classification --e.g. Logistic Regressions-- in a relatively High Dimensional setting (i.e. 300 to 1,500 variables).

I wonder if the Bonferroni and FDR corrections have any relevance for my work.  Your advice will be appreciated.

More specifically, my question is:  Are the Bonferroni and FDR tests applicable in the process of developing a powerful predictive model for Classification purposes and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Each predictor may or may not be truly related to the response.

Suppose you have 1000 predictors and you conduct a hypothesis test for each one with a null hypothesis that the regression coefficient for the relationship between that predictor and the response is 0.  If you use a value of $\alpha$ that is unadjusted, you might risk falsely rejecting the null hypothesis for, say, 50 predictors, on average.

One way to mitigate this risk is to use a Bonferroni Correction (BC), where you replace $\alpha$ with $$\dfrac{\alpha}{1000}$$ where 1000 is the number of tests that you run.

You now state that you will only reject the null given extreme evidence to the contrary.  You want to not call noise signal.

Another strategy, if you want to fit a logistic regression in a high dimensional setting for predictive purposes, is to use Tibshirani's lasso (least absolute shrinkage and selection operator).  To do this, you fit the typical cross entropy loss function associated with logistic regression, but you also constrain your coefficent vector $\theta$ to be sparse by adding to your cost function

$$\lambda \|\theta\|_{1}$$

In essence, to insist that only a few predictors matter, you can increase $\lambda$.  As you might expect, the strongest predictors are the ones that survive.

Lasso bears, in my mind, some superficial resemblance to BC; both methods, by elevating the bar for calling signal signal, defend against the over-interpretation of noise.  In a sense, you might be conducting hypothesis testing with some form of a BC by employing lasso (?).  However, BC seems to be a check on the actual hypothesis testing apparatus (using a distribution over some statistic) whereas lasso imposes a laplacian prior on the coefficient vector.  The similarity between the two might be superficial, therefore.

So, I would say that the problem that you combat when you use BC in the context of hypothesis testing $is$ relevant to predictive modeling in high dimensions.  The solution may or may not be related to BC, but the standard is to use shrinkage.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

If you intend to claim that some predictor X matters (p$\leq$0.05) or several predictors matter, then multiplicity is a huge problem in your setting given the large number of predictors. The Bonferroni correction might be a too conservative way of dealing with that, but most people would expect you to do something about the huge number of predictors you considered, if you want to have such claims believed.

On the other hand, this is much less of a problem, if you just want to get to:"On a training set I developed a prediction algorithm, in which in the end I used the following variables. On an independent test set, which I never looked at during model development, the final model achieves the following performance metrics: . I do not necessarily have strong evidence that each particular variable matters, although here are my variable importance scores."
Even then, some might argue you should consider the multiplicity of outcome measures reported when you give e.g. confidence intervals for, say, both sensitivity and specificity.